# TSQL datetime versus datetime2 compatibility issue and the Native Client 11.0

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, sql-server-native-client

The following code failed when we had to switch to the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver (so that we could upgrade our TLS to 1.2):

```
convert(varchar(15),getdate()+cast(1 as datetime),10)
```

The error was:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : The data types datetime2 and 
>   datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

We can change the T-SQL code to get around this (maybe with a `DATEADD`), but it is legacy code in 250 scripts in our system. Is there something we can do at the native client interface level or is there a global option we can set?

Comment: You should change the legacy code. Adding and subtracting dates from date/datetime/datetime2 should be done with `dateadd`. For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)